# Cannot add service reference to ec2 instance errors=404/405

Tags: winforms, wcf, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, service-reference

I used MS Web Deploy to successfully publish a WCF service to an AWS EC2 Windows 2012 Server. But when I try to add a service reference to a WinForms VB.NET applicaiton, the following error is displayed:

There was an error downloading 'http://ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/PPWebService/Service1.svc'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/PPWebService/Service1.svc'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I tried rebuilding the  client application and adding the service reference again, but received the same result.

I am wondering how to resolve the (405) Method not allowed error or is it even possible to add a service reference to an EC2 instance?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the wsdl url from the browser? if so check if it contains a reference to http:// localhost... and if so try [useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816894.aspx).

Comment: When I enter http://ec2-54-214-64-249.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/PPWebService/Service1.svc in Chrome, I get a 404 error. I verified it is an existing address.

Comment: can you ssh/rdp into the machine and access with localhost?

Comment: Yep. I can ping ec2 as well.

Comment: maybe a firewall issue? (I just can't connect to that url). otherwise turn on wcf logging on the server or use some other network sniffer to see if the request for the page gets there at all